# Beamer frame: add user options

Tags: beamer, key-value

I would like to add 2 more user options to `\frame` command. However, when calling `\frame` with both parameters at the same time in a specific order (the one with implicit value first), it generates an error. Here is a `MWE`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{oneparam}[true]{%
    \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
}
\define@key{beamerframe}{twoparam}{%
    \color{#1}
}
% Default framestyle
\pretocmd{\beamer@@@@frame}
{
    \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}
    \setbeamertemplate{background}{}
}
{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\frame[oneparam]{
    Works
}

\frame[twoparam=red]{
    Works
}

\frame[oneparam, twoparam=green]{
    Fail
}

\frame[twoparam=green, oneparam]{
    Works
}
\end{document}
```

Error message:

> Package keyval Error: twoparam undefined \frame[oneparam,
>   twoparam=red]

Comment: It is not really a solution, but I realised that the problem resides in `\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}` if you change it (say you put `\setbeamertemplate{background}{HELLO}` instead), it works.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `\frame` fires a `\setkeys` and fires another `\setkeys` while the first one is not terminated. A simple experiment shows that nested `\setkeys`'s will not work. So you have to switch to other key-val systems, such as the excellent [pgfkeys](/questions/tagged/pgfkeys).

PS. Beamer includes [pgf](/questions/tagged/pgf) by default, which means that [pgfkeys](/questions/tagged/pgfkeys) is included by default. I do not know why beamer (still) uses `keyval`.